# Magento 2 : How to Place New Tab at The End of Product's Details Tabs?

Tags: magento2, product, tabs

I already created new custom tab using this tutorial:
https://magenticians.com/add-custom-tab-magento-2/

But it is located on left side. I need to place it at end (right side) like it is on this picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Stqen.png

I should be using **move** element like it is mentioned in this manual:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html

But I don't know how to do this.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can give TAB'S priority(position) like below:

```
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.description">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="priority" xsi:type="string">1</argument>.  <!-- you can pass position here -->
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.attributes">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="priority" xsi:type="string">3</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="reviews.tab">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="priority" xsi:type="string">4</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <!-- MY OWN CUSTOM BLOCK ON THE SECOND POSITION -->
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.features" as="features" template="product/view/features.phtml" group="detailed_info">
            <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Features</argument>
                <argument name="priority" xsi:type="string">2</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <!-- MY OWN CUSTOM BLOCK ENDS HERE -->
    </referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that for more recent versions of Magento 2 (2.3.1 onwards) you need to add the new argument in your catalog_module_view.xml for each custom tab.

```
<argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">2</argument>
```