# How to apply changes?

Tags: magento2.2

I implemented this in fresh Magento 2.2.3 instalation:
https://magenticians.com/add-custom-tab-magento-2/

After I make a change in code, like temporarily commented out:

```
<!-- <block class="Magenticians\Mymodule\Block\Mymodule" name="mymodule" template="Magenticians_Mymodule::mymodule.phtml" /> -->
```

and ran these in terminal:
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:clean

...new tab is still there (changes didn't applied)...

I also tried activating developer mode:
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

Changes don't apply...

Please help.

Comment: have you tried removing var/generation ?

Comment: there is no generation directory https://ibb.co/hFjptc

Comment: Id go back and check to see if you have uploaded your code also check the eav_attribute_group just to make sure its not been added to there

Comment: i am working on my local ubuntu machine

Comment: if you followed the above tutorial did you remove the block within catalog_product_view.xml under <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">

Comment: where do you see such a instruction?

Comment: if you want to hide the new tab on the product view you need to remove it or comment it out from the layout xml

Comment: That is what I did. I am solving this issue : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/223690/magento-2-how-to-place-new-tab-at-the-end-of-products-details-tabs/223695#223695 so I tried to comment out block element in mymodule_index_index.xml and I found out it doesn't dissapear so I can't see any changes I make in mymodule_index_index.xml...

Answer (score 0):

You should try removing

```
pub/static/frontend
var/cache
var/page_cache
var/view_preprocessed
```

You can also try running the following command:

```
bin/magento c:f  && bin/magento s:up && bin/magento setup:di:compile && bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```